# Custom Taxonomy to dropdown box on adminside wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, customization, custom-field, metabox

Can I create a country- location hierarchy using custom taxonomy on admin side.  When selecting a country from select box , an another box should see the list of location comes under that country. And also  there must be an option to add new location to under that country. Is there any  hooks, filters or plugin to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use tis plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/acategory-dropdown-list/
It may be help you